# What is the rationale for requiring a column list when inserting into a table with identity column?

Tags: sql-server, identity

When inserting into a table with an `identity` column from some similar staging table, we have to set `IDENTITY_INSERT` to `ON` and specify a column list.

Why do we have to specify a column list in this case?

Wouldn't it be better to specify a change request at Microsoft Connect?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't specify the column list then this implicitly assumes a column list including all user insert-able columns (non `identity`, `rowversion`, `computed`) as below.

```
CREATE TABLE #T
(
C INT IDENTITY,
D INT,
E INT
)

INSERT INTO #T
VALUES (2,3)
```

This is far more generally useful as the most common reason for having an `IDENTITY` column is to allow SQL Server to manage the values.

I suppose it could imply that if there was an extra column in the insert source on an `identity` table that it should generate an execution plan for the explicit `identity_insert` case but not much benefit to this IMO.

Comment: +1 - You can see this behavior in SSMS as well - auto-generated insert scripts don't include the `identity` field in the field list.